# Symfony Mailer email sent in profiler but not received

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-mailer

I try to send email with symfony. I use this code :

```
$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
        ->from('myemail@mydomain.com')
        ->to('mypersonnaltestingemail@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Nouvelle demande de devis !')
        ->htmlTemplate('email/email_project_ask.html.twig')
        ->context([
            'projectAsk' => $projectAsk,
        ])
    ;

    try {
        $this->mailer->send($email);
    } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('app_404_error'));
    }
```

Previously, the same code sent emails, I could not explain what have changed and provoke an error. I writed in my .env file the mailer DSN and even tried to change it (the password for example).

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://myemail@mydomain.com:mypassword@mx1.mail.ovh.net
```

In the profiler, the email is "sent" from the email written in the function.

[Image of the profiler which displays that email is sent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6HC0.png)

But in the facts, when I connect to mypersonnaltestingemail@gmail.com, in my mailbox, I don't see the email...

Can someone could explain me where is the problem and how i can solve it? In the DSN? I am working online in a testing domain like test.mydomain.com... Previously the function and the mailer DSN worked...

Comment: Do you have a `.env.local` file that might be trumping this? Also, have you gone through [all the steps here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24644450/231316)?

Comment: The values and the DSN are in a .env.local, not in a .env file, sorry...

Comment: And yes, all the steps are done...

Comment: Also check your SPF records to make sure you are authorized to send in that fashion

Comment: Did you check other boxes such as spam? for debugging just login from any email client to this email, and try to send emails. If you can send it from email client but not from symfony then search problem in symfony. as @ChrisHaas mentioned it might be server configuration problems.

Comment: I just tried with another smtp with gmail. I have the same problem. Maybe it's a problem with symfony, but I don't really know how to have more information than I have in the profiler... The profiler doesn't give me a lot of informations.

Comment: With gmail, it's not possible to have server configuration problems I think ?

Comment: Gmail has rules for interacting with it, just like every MTA out there. SPF, DKIM, TLS, ports, etc.

Comment: Also, as I remember you need to set up different password for gmail account https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en. And as I said before, download ex. Thunderbird email client, login to your email with app password you generated and try to send email

Comment: Please show `config/packages/dev/mailer.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Symfony with the --docker option, your docker-compose.override.yml file will contain a configuration for mailcatcher when you add symfony mailer.

Hover over "Server" in your profiler bar to reveal a menu and open Webmail from there. Your email should be there.

Comment: It is only if he ran his app with docker. Isn't it ?